# Is async/await syntax really better than manual threading for a programmer or sometimes it is not so useful?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I often see in the Internet that async\await is a "genius innovation" in programming. Sometimes it is, but in some case as I feel it can't shorten a code needed to be written.

If I need 3 parallel tasks (downloads) and I want to do something with results of each downloads (where processing (output SUM to a console) is dependent from each downloads and I need all results simultaneously, as shown at #1), I can do it using Thread and without using async/await as here (some pseudocode because GetByteArray doesn't exist):

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static int length = 0;
        static HttpClient client =
            new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1000000 };
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateMultipleTasksAsync();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static void CreateMultipleTasksAsync()
        {
            Thread th1 = new Thread(ProcessURLAsync);
            th1.Start("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
            Thread th2 = new Thread(ProcessURLAsync);
            th2.Start("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528(VS.110).aspx");
            Thread th3 = new Thread(ProcessURLAsync);
            th3.Start("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67w7t67f.aspx");

            //#2 there I need results of all 3 downloads (so it will wait for all 3 downloads being completed)
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n\r\nTotal bytes returned:  {0}\r\n", Program.length);
        }
        static void ProcessURLAsync(object urlObj)
        {
            string url = (string)urlObj;
            var length = client.GetByteArray(url).Length;
     /*       //#1 there I need only a result of one current download (so it will wait only for current download being completed)
            Console.WriteLine("\n{0,-58} {1}", url, length);*/
            Program.length =+ length;
        }
    }
}
```

or can do it this way using async/await:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateMultipleTasksAsync();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static async Task CreateMultipleTasksAsync()
        {            
        HttpClient client =
                new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1000000 };
            Task<byte[]> download1 =
                client.GetByteArrayAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com");
            Task<byte[]> download2 =
                client.GetByteArrayAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528(VS.110).aspx");
            Task<byte[]> download3 =
                client.GetByteArrayAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67w7t67f.aspx");

            int length1 = (await download1).Length;
            int length2 = (await download2).Length;
            int length3 = (await download3).Length;
            //#1 there I need results of all 3 downloads (so it will wait for all 3 downloads being completed)
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n\r\nTotal bytes returned:  {0}\r\n", length1 + length2 + length3);
        }
    }
}
```

and the async/await-way is really more short and better because all my code is compact and all is in one method CreateMultipleTasksAsync and I shouldn't create additional methods and delegate it.

But if I want to do something with a result of a single download (independently from other downloads, as shown at #2), I need take out a piece of a code into a separate method with only 1 await modifier in this method.

I need additional method because I cant't write code this way:

```
...
            Task<int> download1 =
                ProcessURLAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com", client);
            Task<int> download2 =
                ProcessURLAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528(VS.110).aspx", client);
            Task<int> download3 =
                ProcessURLAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67w7t67f.aspx", client);

            int length1 = (await download1).Length;
            //#3
            Console.WriteLine("\n{0,-58} {1}", "http://msdn.microsoft.com", length1);
            int length2 = (await download2).Length;
            //#4
            Console.WriteLine("\n{0,-58} {1}", "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528(VS.110).aspx", length2);
            int length3 = (await download3).Length;
            //#5
...
```

because in this code a result of download2 is always processed (output to console at #4) after processing a result of download1 (#3) and a result of download3 is always processed (output to console at #5) after processing both results of download1 (#3) and download2 (#4) (processing of different results becomes dependent from processing of other results). And an output order in this case is always the same (even if download3 has been completed much earlier then download1, anyway #5 will be displayed after #3).

But if I want #5 displayed before #3 when download3 has been completed earlier then download1, I'm forced to create an additional method ProcessURLAsync:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateMultipleTasksAsync();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static async Task CreateMultipleTasksAsync()
        {         
        HttpClient client =
                new HttpClient() { MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 1000000 };   
            Task<int> download1 =
                ProcessURLAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com", client);
            Task<int> download2 =
                ProcessURLAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528(VS.110).aspx", client);
            Task<int> download3 =
                ProcessURLAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67w7t67f.aspx", client);

            int length1 = await download1;
            int length2 = await download2;
            int length3 = await download3;
            //#1 there I need results of all 3 downloads (so it will wait for all 3 downloads being completed)
            Console.WriteLine("\r\n\r\nTotal bytes returned:  {0}\r\n", length1 + length2 + length3);
        }
        static async Task<int> ProcessURLAsync(string url, HttpClient client)
        {
            var length = (await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url)).Length;
            //#2 there I need only a result of one current download, independently from other downloads (so it will wait only for current download being completed)
            Console.WriteLine("\n{0,-58} {1}", url, length);
            return length;
        }
    }
}
```

and in this case it isn't so obvious why the async/await-way is better because I need create additional method ProcessURLAsync to process a result of a single download, so my code is so much like a first example's code without async/await.

If we ignore a fact that async/await-way is obviously better than Thread-way by 3 reasons - 1) you should pass url to a delegate as object and then cast it back to string, 2) you can use only local variables to store lengths (length1, length2, length3) without a need to create static property Program.length (because you can't return a value from a delegate), 3) you can't pass more than 1 argument to a delegate so you need to make 'HttpClient client' static instead of local - does it mean that the async/await-way is really better only in situations when: 1) you need only 1 parallel task ; 2) or you need multiple parallel tasks but there is no need to process them separately from each other (only there is a need to process them altogether)?

If none of parallel tasks is dependent from each other and I should process them separately, is there any advantage of syntax async/await?

Comment: Is a sledgehammer better than a hammer? Depends on the situation. Don't forget that Tasks are not Threads. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benwilli/2015/09/10/tasks-are-still-not-threads-and-async-is-not-parallel/

Comment: Please [edit] your post and ask specific question. It is very unclear what you want to achieve... Currently you are comparing incorrect (not thread safe) code with threads running in parallel with sequential calls to several async tasks - and claim that there is no reason to do task... quite confusing.

Comment: Concurrent threads and awaiting async operations are different things.  What exactly are you comparing?

Answer (score 2):

Your final code really is not comparable to threading.  Using a single-threaded SynchronizationContext (default for UI apps) the `ProcessURLAsync` calls execute overlapped, but not in parallel.  The only interruption points are uses of the `await` keyword.

This means that they can safely access the UI and update shared data structures without needing additional synchronization.  This can result in a great reduction of code length and complexity compared to explicit threading.

(Note: As mentioned in the comments, this line that appears in your threaded false equivalent accesses a shared variable without synchronization and therefore suffers a race condition: `Program.length =+ length;`  This is in addition to the total failure to wait for the threads to finish before printing the result.  You may have additional problems if the `HttpClient client` object is not threadsafe.)

Comment: *This is in addition to the total failure to wait for the threads to finish before printing the result.)* - if you mean that I print out a result of Program.length without waiting a completion of all threads - you are right, I just didn't test my first example because it uncompilable. Now I see an error.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things here.

First, the way async works in a console application can be decidedly odd due to differences between the synchronization contexts in UIs vs. console applications, see [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/01/20/await-synchronizationcontext-and-console-apps/).

Secondly, async isn't necessarily the same thing as multithreading. If you do something like `Task.Run(...)` that'll definitely run on the thread pool. However, a "standard" async operation isn't the same.

My standard illustration of this is as follows: suppose you go a restaurant with 10 people. When the waiter comes by, the first person he asks for his order isn't ready; however, the other 9 people are. Thus, the waiter asks the other 9 people for their orders and then comes back to the original guy. (It's definitely *not* the case that they'll get a second waiter to wait for the original guy to be ready to order and doing so probably wouldn't save much time anyway). That's how async/await typically works (the exception being that some of the Task Parallel library calls, like Thread.Run(...), actually *are* executing on other threads - in our illustration, bringing in a second waiter - so make sure you check the documentation for which is which).

Note that, if you're not using a synchronization context in your console application, there are much fewer guarantees as to which thread async methods will actually run on, so it might not behave exactly how you'd expect in this case.

Really, which one you end up using depends on whether your task is CPU-bound. If it's not a CPU-bound operation (i.e. it's mostly just waiting around for a result from a server, external hardware, etc.) the performance difference of using a thread vs. async probably won't be too significant - you can do the equivalent of telling the waiter to "come back to me." For CPU-bound operations, however, you probably want to put it on a separate thread.

Also, in the code sample you posted there doesn't seem to be a reason to await the result of the operations in every case; if the caller doesn't have an immediate need for the result you don't have to await it. In fact, "kicking off" the process without waiting for it can be a big performance boost. The caveat, of course, is to make sure that all of your tasks finish before you close the console application.

Hopefully that clears things up a little; if not please let me know and I can edit my answer.